# Understanding Confidence Sets

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm having trouble understanding the formal definition of a confidence set. This is the definition that I am working under.

**Definition (Confidence Set):** Let the data be distributed according to the random variable $X$, which depends on a parameter $\theta$ taken from a parameter space $\Theta$. A $(1-\alpha)$ confidence set, denoted $\mathcal{C}(X)$, is a subset of the parameter space $\Theta$ that only depends on $X$ such that
$$\inf_{\theta \in \Theta} \mathbb{P}_\theta \left( \theta \in \mathcal{C}(X) \right) \geq 1-\alpha .$$

I think I clearly have a misunderstanding of what this means because I don't see why we can't just always make the confidence set be the parameter space
$$\mathcal{C}(X)=\Theta$$
and trivially satisfy the above inequality all the time. I would appreciate a simple example of how this definition works.

Comment: (+1) Your statement is correct--and, as you point out, trivial at the same time. You definitely could make the entire parameter space your confidence set in every problem you address, but in short order you would have no clients and no career as a statistician because your information would not be helpful!

Comment: @whuber Ok, that makes sense. So if I were to make the following statement, would I be correct?: "For a 95% confidence level, under repeated draws of $X$ (repeated experiments), the percent of computed confidence sets that contain the true parameter will be at least 95%, **because each and every parameter in the parameter space will appear in at least 95% of the computed confidence sets**."

Comment: every C.I. is associated with a set of hypothesis test. Want to test $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$? see if $\theta_0$ is in the C.I.. This means every C.I. will be associated with some power of test. A C.I. (I should really have said C.S.) which is the entire parameter space has a power of 0. As whuber said, not very useful.

Comment: No, the bold part of that statement is not correct. (As a counterexample, consider repeating an experiment in which $n\gt 1$ iid Normal$(0,1)$ values are drawn and the usual (symmetric Student t two-sided) confidence interval for the mean is constructed. Only infinitesimally few of those CIs will extend beyond, say, the interval $[-100,100]$ even though all real numbers are possible values of the mean.) A diagram that has helped me understand this concept appears at the beginning of  http://www.quantdec.com/envstats/notes/class_12/ucl.htm#Chebyshev under "The theory of confidence intervals."